# Chrome extension - select2 library working into console but not in content.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Hello i'm working on a google chrome extension and workaround with https://select2.github.io .

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Extension Test",
    "description": "Test extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.mywebsite.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.js", "content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.3.js","background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webNavigation",
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Here is what i run directly into console:

```
$('#myselect2').select2('open');
```

Then the same code into content js is not working and firing the following error:

```
content.js:151 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

Is it possible to open select menu from extension to content of website and if so how ?

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing with

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Extension Test",
    "description": "Test extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.mywebsite.com/*"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.js", "content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.3.js","background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webNavigation",
        "*://*/*"
    ]
}
```

you are missing a '"' in the matches property.

Comment: That's just a typo when placing the question.

Comment: Did you add the select2 js ?

Comment: Can you please a screenshot of the content of your directory? And update ur code to include the select2 in the question ?

Comment: This is the error i receive when i include select2 library: `The select2('open') method was called on an element that is not using Select2.`

I'm pretty sure that this element is using the Select2

Comment: That's because you need to initiate $(your-element).select2()  before calling any other select2 methods.

It would be helpful if you update the manifest in your question and show us the files structure in your project so I can better assist.

Comment: If i do that `$(your-element).select2()` it creates another element into the page.

Comment: That's how select2 works. select2 replaces your input by displaying an html wrap-up of another input to be displayed. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by calling the select2 methods without initiating it.
did you manage to load select2 in the first place? because you are deviating from your main question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not including the select2 plugin in your extension. Download it into your extension and, in your manifest, add:

```
"js": ["jquery-1.11.3.js", "select2.min.js", "content.js"]
```